# Titanium appcelerator pull to refresh load data on scroll iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

which is a good widget for "pull to refresh" and "load data on scroll" that works on tableview and in both platform iOS and Android?

Comment: have you actually searched?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a Pull To Refresh Module/widget or lib. A quick google search would've showed you this.

https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.pullToRefresh/

Example implementation (taken from github)

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="myCollection" />
    <Window>
        <Widget id="ptr" src="nl.fokkezb.pullToRefresh" onRelease="myRefresher">
            <ListView>
                <ListSection dataCollection="myCollection">
                    <ListItem title="{title}" />
                </ListSection>
            </ListView>
        </Widget>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```